# Craft cms - page not found

Tags: php, content-management-system, craftcms

After setting up a template file `article.html` in `craft/templates` folder, and creating the section article with the `uri` `article` and setting the entry template as `article` in the admin on trying to see the live preview of the page when I go to it in the entries list I get a craft page with the error:

> Page not found

I thought it might have something with cache maybe, so I cleared that, but I still got the same error. Why I am getting this error, and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a database not updating issue, have you tried making a backup of your current database and start with a fresh one?

If not, then check .htaccess and your routes.

Answer (score 0):

1. First crate a 404.twig file.
2. Open general.php file "config/general.php" and change the devMode to false.